# Degree centrality algorithm returns only 0.0 as score

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to run the degree centrality algorithm on my dataset. The submodel of my query looks like this:

```
(transfer:Transfer)-[:PARENT_TRANSFER]->(hasUnderlyingBatch:HasUnderlyingBatch)
```

The query that I'm trying to run:

```
CALL algo.degree.stream("Transfer", "PARENT_TRANSFER", {direction:"outgoing"}) YIELD nodeId, score 
RETURN nodeId, score ORDER BY score DESC
```

I have verified that these relations exist, but I received a score of 0.0 for each record nonetheless.

When I implement the query myself, I do get proper results:

```
MATCH (t:Transfer) 
RETURN t.Code, size((t)-[:PARENT_TRANSFER]->()) as score 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Could anyone explain to me why I'm not getting the proper results when using the degree centrality algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PARENT_TRANSFER` relationship is between a node `Transfer` and `HasUnderlyingBatch`.

Or in the call of the algo, you are only using nodes with a label `Transfer`, so it's normal that you have no result.

What you have to do is a [cypher projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/projected-graph-model/cypher-projection/) of your graph, if you really want to do an algo between yours `Transfer` and `HasUnderlyingBatch` (but it seems weird for me, because you mix apples and bananas).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for providing an alternative approach! I do think it's weird since there are a lot of networks in which there are relations between nodes with different labels. We're modelling for a supply chain network so I want to know for which plant there are the most outgoing batches of a specific product. In that sense, relating apples and bananas does seem to make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older thread, but since I've just wrestled with this, I'll add in hopes it helps others. The fancy term is unipartite support. That's what this algorithm helps. Meaning, as in the example in the literature, (:A)-[:R]->(:A). So a graph becoming a bipartite or greater graph - i.e., adding a "B" node label, will create zeros in the score return value because that's how they built it. UNLESS, you put in nulls for the parameters in the algo for nodes and relationships. Some have given advice for that "trick" to be for making both the first two values in the algo nulls: [CALL algo.degree(null, null...]. That works for getting your score>0, but may not give you the right degree number when you have multiple relationships and have relationships to a node.

But, if you put in null for the first parameter (that's for the nodes) and the relationship you want (say ":R"), then you get the degree for all nodes that have incoming/outgoing/both and your score value will be right. My advice to anyone using graphs, in spite of the inconvenience, to always use directional graphs. It's honest, "correct" and will make things like degree scores easier to get right. My 0.02.

The docs could be way better. It's not intuitive but I hope this helps. Degree Centrality is a fundamental and very valuable algo.

One final note, if you're moving to 3.5 (not 4.x yet), move from algo.* to the gds.*. I've not checked yet, but I'm hoping they have improved this algorithm to make this a bit clearer.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @LPLP1313! Checking out the new GDS algorithms is on my shortlist :-)

Answer (score 1):

These algorithms find a central node within the same types of nodes (i.e. check relationships between the same type of nodes).

In your case relationships `PARENT_TRANSFER` is between two different types of nodes: `Transfer` and `HasUnderlyingBatch`. However, Algorithm is searching for `PARENT_TRANSFER` between the `Transfer` nodes.

You can verify this on the graph which has any relationships between the same type of nodes like `FOLLOW` relationship between `Person` nodes in the social network graph.

I don't see any configuration setting for ignoring the same label search in the documentation.